# What is the most important Purana for Saiva denomination?

Tags: shiva, puranas, shaivism, sects

For Vaishnavas, Bhagavad Purana (Srimad Bhagavat) is the most important Purana. For Saktas, Devi Purana (Srimad Devi Bhagavat) is the most important Purana. What is the most important Purana for the Saiva sect?

There are Siva Purana, Linga Purana. Apparently, both are related to Siva. But which Purana the Saivas consider as the primary text for them, I have no idea. Do they at all consider any specific Purana as the main text?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer different from Shiva Puran?

Comment: @sbharti There are Siva Purana, Linga Purana. Apparently, both are related to Siva. But which Purana the Saivas consider as canonical for them, I have no idea. Whether they at all consider any Purana as central text to their doctrine, I do not know. That's what I was wondering.

Comment: Technically it should be the Bhagavatam as well, because it seems to be the only Purana with a claim to best Purana. (Technically you could argue the Brahmananda is the original as all Puranas are called it, but as per Puranas we see, it is the Bhagavatam)

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa Which Bhagavatam are you talking about? The Devi Bhagavatam also says that it is the best among all Puranas.

Comment: @Rickross The name of the Devi Bhagavatam implies it is supposed to be part of the Bhagavatam, otherwise why is Bhagavatam male? They also have the same narrator so it fits. https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk01ch02.htm

Comment: @Rickross It is a prime example of how the Upapuranas and Mahapuranas of "different sects" put together will cause outrage.

Comment: @Rickross Also there does not seem to be a source that unambiguously puts the Devi Bhagavata as a Mahapurana. Wikipedia claims the Shiva Purana says so, but a site search of the Shiva Purana reveals nothing. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puranas

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa Devi Purana is not a Mahapurana. In fact, there is a list of 18 Mahapuranas mentioned in Devi Purana itself. Despite that, the Devi Purana is a canonical text for Shaktas.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay It is an Upapurana. Upapuranas are supposed to be part of the Mahapuranas but people will get mad at which one is supposed to be in which Mahapurana.